# Obj-C: Typedefs across classes?

Tags: objective-c, enums, typedef

I want to typedef an enum that is common across several classes. I could:

- 1 Make the typedef in a class that the others inherit from directly
- 2 Typedef the enum for each of the classes.
- 3 Create a category for NSObject and typedef the enum there.

Whilst the first option requires no repetition -- and I think this is the best of the three -- it just feels wrong creating a whole new class just for just one enum. Is this anti-pattern? Is there a better way?

Answer (score 4):

Usually done like this:

```
#ifndef SomeEnum_enum
#define SomeEnum_enum

typedef enum {
    SomeEnumOne,
    SomeEnumTwo,
    SomeEnumThree
} SomeEnum;

#endif
```

You have to put your enum in your **.h** file, it can be one of a class, a separate file just for enums, a category, it really doesn't matter.

Now you can put it wherever you want, you just have to include the .h file

Comment: Yeah. Just put it in a header file and #import that from any class that needs it. C `typedefs` aren't scoped to Objective-C classes in any way.